# How to set queuing mode from simulation page in AnyLogic

Tags: queue, agent, anylogic, queuing

I want to set up the queuing mode from simulation page in my AnyLogic model. I have a *combo box* with two options: **FIFO** and fewest remaining operations (**FRO**). The chosen option is saved in the variable *strategie* from type String.

In the main page I have the parameter *Strategie* which is linked to the variable. Now I need a function to change the queueing mode. For FIFO I want to take the standard FIFO Queuing Mode and for FRO the agent comparison with the function: `agent1.remaining<agent2.remaining` (this variable is already defined in the agent). 
This is what I already tried.

```
if (Strategie.equals("FiFo"))
queue.set_queuing(Queue.QUEUING_FIFO);
else {
if (Strategie.equals("FRO"))
????;
else {
error ("Error in Queuing Decision");
}}
```

but this does not work as the value in the queuing bracktes could not be assigned to a variable. So I’m looking for a correct function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want to make a customized handling of queue, use a wait block instead of a queue block.. FRO doesn't exist in AnyLogic and you will have to program it yourself

Comment: Plus take a look at a Java tutorial on control flow; the syntax of your if...else is incorrect (missing curly brackets and incorrect semi-colon after second if).